# Python PIP Install Cache Path [windows]

Tags: python, windows, pip

I don't have enough space on my C drive (PRIMARY) and can't install packages due to not having enough space, I have installed my python onto my D drive.

however when i try to install i get this error

`error: could not install packages due to an environmenterror: [errno 28] no space left on device`

I have even made a symlink (directory) to point the pip folder from my windows user profile appdata folder to a folder named pip on my d drive, even when doing this I still get the error listed above.

Thanks for the support and help <3

Edit: I have tried using a virtual enviroment, but still without success

Comment: Have you tried using a virtual environment?

Comment: yes i have, still doesn't work

Comment: Are you sure there is adequate space on your computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you used the --target when installed the packages ?

Comment: also, does the "--target" param work with  "-r install" command?

Comment: If you want to install a package in a specific location which is not the default one , you should implicit do it, pip install --target='D:\XXXX' "package name"

Comment: i get the same issue using this command `pip install tensorflow-gpu --target "D:/pip/"`

Comment: even this command doesn't work `pip install tensorflow-gpu --target "D:/pip/" --no-cache-dir`

Comment: i'll just use a virtual machine and have that on my other drive.